# Can you get an access token for Azure with a username and password and without using a client_id via web request?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-authentication

Scenario: I'm trying to get an access token using a web request as I cannot use Azure PowerShell. The situation I'm trying to replicate is `Get-AzAccessToken`, where I've authenticated using my username and password and I'm not supplying a `client_id`.

I can get an access token in PowerShell using the following:

```
$postParams = @{
  grant_type = 'password'
  client_id  = $ClientId
  username   = $Username
  password   = $Password
  scope      = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
}

Write-Host "Getting access token for app"
  
Invoke-RestMethod `
  -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token `
  -Method POST `
  -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded `
  -Body $postParams
```

I can also get an access token by using the Azure PowerShell command `Get-AzAccessToken`.

Is it possible to get an access token without using a client_id? If not, is `Get-AzAccessToken` using a `client_id`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without a client id. And yes, Azure PowerShell is using one. The best way to implement this is to register your own app and use its client id.

Comment: Do you know what the `client_id` used by Azure PowerShell is?